# Mysql Load data infile ignore 1 lines not working

Tags: mysql

I want to import a CSV file to my Mysql table using Load data infile: here's my current code :

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '../myfile.csv'
          INTO TABLE data 
        FIELDS
            TERMINATED BY ','
            ENCLOSED BY '"'
            ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@f1,@f2...) set `f1`=@f1,...,fk=13 ;
```

This is the first part of the csv file :

```
Timestamp,FromName,FromID,FromA,FromAID,FromURL,ToCName,ToCID,ToCTarget,ToAName,ToAID,ToAURL,UUID,Model,OS,Country,Type,Value
"2012-10-29 07:02:20","NH","4f7898654fgh02","Halloween Game","589754hj67d00021","78643609","","","","Game 1™","4f754hj67d00014","58975449","988675ffgh555f3284530","iPhone","5.1.1","GB","cpi","0.5"
```

this gives me a 0 rows inserted, but if i replace IGNORE 1 LINES with IGNORE 0 LINES the file is imported successfully (of course without ignoring the first line).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not enough information about the problem. Add the file `myfile.csv` also.

Comment: I edited the question, i hope it's clearer this way.

Comment: I do not see any problems with this. Did you get an error during loading data?

Answer (score 5):

Removing this line solved the problem :

```
ESCAPED BY '"'
```

**working code :**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '../myfile.csv'
          INTO TABLE data 
        FIELDS
            TERMINATED BY ','
            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@f1,@f2...) set `f1`=@f1,...,fk=13 ;
```

Comment: Do you understand _why_ it solved the problem? If you had `"` within one of the field values in your CSV, would this same approach still work? And why did you need `ENCLOSED BY '\"'` instead of `ENCLOSED BY '"'`?